# Symfony 4 - Doctrine : Object not hydrated when using get method

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, serializable

Hello I have a problem in my project Symfony 4. I have a Validator entity that contains a serial number, and is associated with a User:

**Validateur.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ValidateurRepository")
 */
class Validateur
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Ordre de validation
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\SortablePosition
     */
    private $ordre;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="validateurs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $validateur;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Retourne l'ordre de validation du validateur
     *
     * @return integer|null
     */
    public function getOrdre(): ?int
    {
        return $this->ordre;
    }

    /**
     * Insère l'ordre de validation du validateur
     *
     * @param integer $ordre
     * @return self
     */
    public function setOrdre(int $ordre): self
    {
        $this->ordre = $ordre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValidateur(): ?User
    {
        return $this->validateur;
    }

    public function setValidateur(?User $validateur): self
    {
        $this->validateur = $validateur;

        return $this;
    }


    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->validateur->getFullname();
    }
}
```

But oddly when I dump a validator object, I have the infos, but in the associated User object, it is not initialized and I have only the ID of the user. Other values remain in null. My user object is not hydrated.

[image]

And I noticed that it happens on almost all my validator objects. I would even say that there is only validator object which I am connected with the user, which sends me a validator object with the complete user

PS: In my User entity, I implement Serializable with these two functions :

```
/**
 * String representation of object
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
 * @return string the string representation of the object or null
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize([
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Constructs the object
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.unserialize.php
 * @param string $serialized <p>
 * The string representation of the object.
 * </p>
 * @return void
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
}
```

Comment: Please read how Symfony/Doctrine handles [Associations](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#fetching-related-objects), you have Proxies for non-fetched objects which is working as expected.

Comment: So if I read the doc 'correctly, does that mean that Doctrine is doing a lazy load of the User entity? So currently doing a simple $ validator-> getUser () I get an unhydrated User object, but if after that I want to treat this object (for example by doing an if condition ($ validator-> getUser () -> getNom () == 'Jimmy'), then Doctrine will moisturize the User object, so in the end it's not a real problem I have, that's quite normal? ( sorry for my english i'm french)

Comment: yes, exactly. at first you have a Proxy class of your User, once you call one of its properties, a database request will retrieve the "full" object. So ususally this isn't an issue. If you face a real issue (e.g. you need hydration earlier, you see too many extra DB calls etc.) you can ask a new question with details.,

Comment: Ah, you reassure me because yesterday I spent 6 hours trying many things, not understanding why the objects were not hydrated. I understand better now, and it's true that it's pretty much optimized to work like that. Good if it does not cause any problems in the end everything is fine! Thank you very much for your time !